# How would I prove that these two expressions are equivalent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I want to figure out a way to simpilfy

$$x* \frac{1-\frac{|0-x|}{0-x}}{2}$$

to show that it is the same as

$$\frac{x+|x|}{2}$$

Or go the other way around and complicate the second equation so that it looks the same. I've been having trouble figuring out how to manipulate the 0-x that is inside the absolute value.

I get about this far then am not sure how to continue.

$$\frac{x-\frac{|-x^2|}{-x}}{2}$$

---

background context:

I needed an equation that took a number and set all the negative values to 0. I've already created a function in the past that took any number, and set the value below a certain threshold to zero:

$$x* \frac{1-\frac{|t-x|}{t-x}}{2}$$

where `t` is the threshold. So I could put in like `17` and anything less than `17` would be set to `0`.

But I knew since the threshold in this case was `0` that probably meant I could cancel a bunch of stuff out and simplify the function. Then someone I work with offered the second function. And after checking the logic, it does have the exact same behavior or setting all negative numbers to be `0`.

My equation tries to set the number to either `1` or `-1`, then shifts it over to be `2` or `0`, cuts it in half to be `1` or `0`, then multiplies by the original value.

Their equation is just set the number to `2x` if it's positive, or `0` if it's negative. Then divides by `2` to get the original value, or it'll stay stuck at `0`.

I was wondering if there were any edge cases where these two equations provided different answers, and want to practice math a bit. But still pretty bad at knowing all the algebra rules out there for simplification.

Comment: What happens when $x=0$ for the first expression?  You have a division by zero error.

Answer (score -1):

Recall that $|{-x}|$ is equal to $|x|$ for all $x$. Thus,
$$x \cdot \frac{1 - \frac{|0 - x|}{0 - x}}{2} = \frac{x}{1} \cdot\frac{1 - \frac{|{-x}|}{-x}}{2} = \frac{x\left(1 + \frac{|x|}{x}\right)}{1 \cdot2} = \frac{x + |x|}{2}.$$

Comment: This is all well and fine for when $x\neq 0$... but as I alluded to in my comment above, when $x=0$ you have the first expression is undefined due to a division by zero error.  $0\times \frac{0}{0}$ is undefined, so you can't say that $x\times \frac{|x|}{x}=|x|$.

Comment: The two expressions are equal *almost everywhere*, specifically for every nonzero $x$, and the limit as $x$ *approaches* zero is the same for both expressions.  However, since the one expression is undefined for $x=0$ and the other expression *is* defined for $x=0$, they are distinct and should be treated as such.

Comment: hmm interesting, i remember that with absolute values sometimes you can split the problem into multiple parts for various situations. Would that be applicable here? How do I know if there are other edge cases besides 0?

Comment: @JMoravitz I think you can say $x \times \frac{|x|}{x} = |x|$. You can't say they're the same function on their respective natural domains.